# How to stop intent service after closing app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, service

I have added Google Now search within my application. The way it works is, the user types something in the EditText object and oonce they press the button, this intent runs -

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                String term = searchInput.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
                startActivity(intent);
```

However I am having issues killing the service after the intent has been launched.
calling `finish();`after the intent will not work unless I am directing the intent to a different class itself.

Here's a video preview fo what I mean, you can clearly see I am pressing home to close the app but when I reopen it . It opens to the Google Now app. But when pressing back, it stops. How exactly can I get the intent to stop after I press the home key?

And my app is a dialogue type app so I have excluded it from the recent menu because of allot of reasons. Everywhere else the app kills itself as soon as the user exits it but here the service keeps running.

Video - [Video Preview](https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdjxybojmzdrgv/demo.mp4?dl=0)

I have also tried many questions answers, have researched but nothing has helped so far. I may be doing something wrong. Could someone kindly help me out here, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

A started service must manage its own lifecycle. That is, the system does not stop or destroy the service unless it must recover system memory and the service continues to run after `onStartCommand()` returns. So, the service must stop itself by calling `stopSelf()` or another component can stop it by calling `stopService()`.

Answer (score 0):

use stopSelf() upon compleetion of task assigned to service.
And if you want to finishs ervice when application finishes, then in onDestroy(), call stopService() after checking whether its running or not, such method can be used:

```
public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Activity pActivity) {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) pActivity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
return true;
}
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to stop service from activity use below code:

```
stopService(new Intent(yourMainActivity.this,yourIntentService.class));
```

or you can write condition in service to stop itself like below:

```
if(check your condition here)
   stopSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to stop an IntentService - it will terminate itself when it has no more work to do.

- It runs on separate worker thread.
- Multiple intents are queued on the same worker thread.

So even if your Activity was destroyed from where this service was started it will continue performing its tasks until all the queued ones are complete and after completion it is automatically terminated.

Caution: It's important that your application stops its services when it's done working, to avoid wasting system resources and consuming battery power. If necessary, other components can stop the service by calling stopService(). Even if you enable binding for the service, you must always stop the service yourself if it ever received a call to onStartCommand().

stopService()  : Request that a given application service be stopped. If the service is not running, nothing happens. Otherwise it is stopped. Note that calls to startService() are not counted -- this stops the service no matter how many times it was started.

Note: that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed.